# How to make a dynamic slider with jssor slider and passing the image path dynamically in asp.net?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jssor

I want to  pass the  path at the down  below of the page.Please help.

I want to add the dynamically add the path from the database to this page.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

        var jssor_1_SlideshowTransitions = [
          {$Duration:1200,x:0.3,$During:{$Left:[0.3,0.7]},$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
          {$Duration:1200,x:-0.3,$SlideOut:true,$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
          {$Duration:1200,x:-0.3,$During:{$Left:[0.3,0.7]},$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
          {$Duration:1200,x:0.3,$SlideOut:true,$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
          {$Duration:1200,y:0.3,$During:{$Top:[0.3,0.7]},$Easing:{$Top:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
          {$Duration:1200,y:-0.3,$SlideOut:true,$Easing:{$Top:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
          {$Duration:1200,y:-0.3,$During:{$Top:[0.3,0.7]},$Easing:{$Top:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
          {$Duration:1200,y:0.3,$SlideOut:true,$Easing:{$Top:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
          {$Duration:1200,x:0.3,$Cols:2,$During:{$Left:[0.3,0.7]},$ChessMode:{$Column:3},$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
          {$Duration:1200,x:0.3,$Cols:2,$SlideOut:true,$ChessMode:{$Column:3},$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
          {$Duration:1200,y:0.3,$Rows:2,$During:{$Top:[0.3,0.7]},$ChessMode:{$Row:12},$Easing:{$Top:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
          {$Duration:1200,y:0.3,$Rows:2,$SlideOut:true,$ChessMode:{$Row:12},$Easing:{$Top:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
          {$Duration:1200,y:0.3,$Cols:2,$During:{$Top:[0.3,0.7]},$ChessMode:{$Column:12},$Easing:{$Top:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
          {$Duration:1200,y:-0.3,$Cols:2,$SlideOut:true,$ChessMode:{$Column:12},$Easing:{$Top:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
          {$Duration:1200,x:0.3,$Rows:2,$During:{$Left:[0.3,0.7]},$ChessMode:{$Row:3},$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
          {$Duration:1200,x:-0.3,$Rows:2,$SlideOut:true,$ChessMode:{$Row:3},$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
          {$Duration:1200,x:0.3,y:0.3,$Cols:2,$Rows:2,$During:{$Left:[0.3,0.7],$Top:[0.3,0.7]},$ChessMode:{$Column:3,$Row:12},$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Top:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
          {$Duration:1200,x:0.3,y:0.3,$Cols:2,$Rows:2,$During:{$Left:[0.3,0.7],$Top:[0.3,0.7]},$SlideOut:true,$ChessMode:{$Column:3,$Row:12},$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Top:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
          {$Duration:1200,$Delay:20,$Clip:3,$Assembly:260,$Easing:{$Clip:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
          {$Duration:1200,$Delay:20,$Clip:3,$SlideOut:true,$Assembly:260,$Easing:{$Clip:$Jease$.$OutCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
          {$Duration:1200,$Delay:20,$Clip:12,$Assembly:260,$Easing:{$Clip:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
          {$Duration:1200,$Delay:20,$Clip:12,$SlideOut:true,$Assembly:260,$Easing:{$Clip:$Jease$.$OutCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2}
        ];

        var jssor_1_options = {
          $AutoPlay: true,
          $SlideshowOptions: {
            $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,
            $Transitions: jssor_1_SlideshowTransitions,
            $TransitionsOrder: 1
          },
          $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
            $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$
          },
          $ThumbnailNavigatorOptions: {
            $Class: $JssorThumbnailNavigator$,
            $Cols: 10,
            $SpacingX: 8,
            $SpacingY: 8,
            $Align: 360
          }
        };

        var jssor_1_slider = new $JssorSlider$("jssor_1", jssor_1_options);

        /*responsive code begin*/
        /*you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizing*/
        function ScaleSlider() {
            var refSize = jssor_1_slider.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
            if (refSize) {
                refSize = Math.min(refSize, 800);
                jssor_1_slider.$ScaleWidth(refSize);
            }
            else {
                window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
            }
        }
        ScaleSlider();
        $(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
        $(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
        $(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
        /*responsive code end*/
    });

</script>
<style>
    /* jssor slider arrow navigator skin 05 css */
    /*
    .jssora05l                  (normal)
    .jssora05r                  (normal)
    .jssora05l:hover            (normal mouseover)
    .jssora05r:hover            (normal mouseover)
    .jssora05l.jssora05ldn      (mousedown)
    .jssora05r.jssora05rdn      (mousedown)
    .jssora05l.jssora05lds      (disabled)
    .jssora05r.jssora05rds      (disabled)
    */
    .jssora05l, .jssora05r {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        /* size of arrow element */
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        cursor: pointer;
        background: url('img/a17.png') no-repeat;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .jssora05l { background-position: -10px -40px; }
    .jssora05r { background-position: -70px -40px; }
    .jssora05l:hover { background-position: -130px -40px; }
    .jssora05r:hover { background-position: -190px -40px; }
    .jssora05l.jssora05ldn { background-position: -250px -40px; }
    .jssora05r.jssora05rdn { background-position: -310px -40px; }
    .jssora05l.jssora05lds { background-position: -10px -40px; opacity: .3; pointer-events: none; }
    .jssora05r.jssora05rds { background-position: -70px -40px; opacity: .3; pointer-events: none; }

    /* jssor slider thumbnail navigator skin 01 css */
    /*
    .jssort01 .p            (normal)
    .jssort01 .p:hover      (normal mouseover)
    .jssort01 .p.pav        (active)
    .jssort01 .p.pdn        (mousedown)
    */
    .jssort01 .p {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 72px;
        height: 72px;
    }

    .jssort01 .t {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        border: none;
    }

    .jssort01 .w {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .jssort01 .c {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 68px;
        height: 68px;
        border: #000 2px solid;
        box-sizing: content-box;
        background: url('img/t01.png') -800px -800px no-repeat;
        _background: none;
    }

    .jssort01 .pav .c {
        top: 2px;
        _top: 0px;
        left: 2px;
        _left: 0px;
        width: 68px;
        height: 68px;
        border: #000 0px solid;
        _border: #fff 2px solid;
        background-position: 50% 50%;
    }

    .jssort01 .p:hover .c {
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 70px;
        height: 70px;
        border: #fff 1px solid;
        background-position: 50% 50%;
    }

    .jssort01 .p.pdn .c {
        background-position: 50% 50%;
        width: 68px;
        height: 68px;
        border: #000 2px solid;
    }

    * html .jssort01 .c, * html .jssort01 .pdn .c, * html .jssort01 .pav .c {
        /* ie quirks mode adjust */
        width /**/: 72px;
        height /**/: 72px;
    }

</style>
<div id="jssor_1" style="position: relative; margin: 0 auto; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 800px; height: 456px; overflow: hidden; visibility: hidden; background-color: #24262e;">
    <!-- Loading Screen -->
    <div data-u="loading" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
        <div style="filter: alpha(opacity=70); opacity: 0.7; position: absolute; display: block; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
        <div style="position:absolute;display:block;background:url('img/loading.gif') no-repeat center center;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;height:100%;"></div>
    </div>
    <div data-u="slides" style="cursor: default; position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 800px; height: 356px; overflow: hidden;">
        <div data-p="144.50">
            <img data-u="image" src="img/01.jpg" />
            <img data-u="thumb" src="img/thumb-01.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="jssor_1" style="position: relative; margin: 0 auto; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 800px; height: 456px; overflow: hidden; visibility: hidden; background-color: #24262e;">
    <!-- Loading Screen -->
    <div data-u="loading" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
        <div style="filter: alpha(opacity=70); opacity: 0.7; position: absolute; display: block; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
        <div style="position:absolute;display:block;background:url('img/loading.gif') no-repeat center center;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;height:100%;"></div>
    </div>
    <div data-u="slides" style="cursor: default; position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 800px; height: 356px; overflow: hidden;">
        <!-- load image paths from database, and write slides html code here -->
```

[See define slides html code](http://www.jssor.com/development/define-slides-html-code.html)